# How to make a scrolling background?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a Shooter game like "1943" and "Jamestown". I was wondering how I would make the scrolling background to simulate moving forward and How would I make this efficient? I was thinking about using a animated GIF or to make a looping BitMap. Please could someone help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just need to scroll left/right or up/down too?

Comment: try gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Scrolling Up, however with the ability of going left and right slightly when reaching the side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the XNA framework for game development to develop a game that will use the computer's resources efficiently for smooth gameplay and frame rates.  There are a number of books and online tutorials available.

If you're wanting a quick and dirty vertical background scroll in a windows form, you could always place a panel control inside another panel, set the outer panel to not display scrollbars, and make the inner panel twice as tall (or more), and set the background texture of the inner panel to be the background image you want to display.  You can then animate the inner panel to move from top to bottom and reset back to the top when it reaches the bottom.  Also be sure to design your background image so that the view at the top and the view at the bottom are the same for a smooth transition when the panel gets reset.  You'll also want to call panel.Refresh() when you move the panel.

All that said, the XNA framework is really the way to go for game development.